# Intercept Server Reponse And Forawrd To Another PHP File

Tags: php, apache

Is there any way in plain PHP and Apache to intercept a response from a request to an Apache server and then forward all that data to a PHP script that can do some post processing?

In context, if the query parameter `store=true` is specified in a url for report generation (e.g. Excel, CSV) I need a Middleware of sorts that will take the response and forward it to another php file that will then store it on the server.

I'm aware I can add the check to each report file (there are hundreds of different reports) and do the saving logic there, but it would be nice if there was some way to handle this across the board.

I feel like what I'm describing is essentially a Middleware pattern, without a framework, and at the server/ htaccess level.

Comment: What is that generates the report file? Can't that code also send the data where it needs to go?

Comment: @ADyson in theory yes, but there are hundreds of these reports. that'd be a lot of copy paste i feel like. im looking into php_value auto_append_file and auto_prepend_file, im thinking these are what i need.

Comment: One option is to literally put a server in front of your processing that intercepts everything. This can be a physical or virtual one.

Comment: You can also just route all requests to a single file, have that invoke your code, and then save it somewhere

Comment: `there are hundreds of these reports`...ok but there isn't perhaps a php script which generates a report on demand and provides the result to the user, when given the necessary parameters?

Comment: @ADyson haha i wish, if there was one central entry point this could be avoided. This was a rather large project i inherited, about 15 years of "copy and paste it again" code design. I put an answer on here if you want to give your input, it seems to be working fine enough.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, not sure if it is the best but it works globally:

I was able to add `auto_prepend_file` to my `.htaccess` file, also can be added to `php.ini` and then call the `register_shutdown_function` to include the after request middleware. (`auto_append_file` wasnt working for me if an error threw, or someone called `die()` or `exit()`)

It works as follows.

**.htaccess**

`php_value auto_prepend_file middleware/middleware_pre.php`

**middleware_pre.php**

```
//First add a hook for the shutdown to run code after a request
$postMiddlewareAdded = false;
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    global $postMiddlewareAdded;
 
    if(!$postMiddlewareAdded){     
        $postMiddlewareAdded = true;
        include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/middleware/middelware_post.php');
    }
});

echo "Yay. I run before every request";
```

**middleware_post.php**

```
echo "Yay. I run after every request.";
```